# NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for Payment:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have model Payment. When create a record in rails console, its showing "NoMethodError: undefined method `create!' for Payment:Module" at the same time, I am typing 'Payment' in rails console its doesn't show attributes. I have three attributes in this table(:name, :transaction_id, :amount). What is an issue? I made any mistake or anything else.
Please help me out.

Comment: does your model extend ActiveRecord:Base ? you can copy your payment model here if possible

Comment: Thanks for reply, I created a module name same as model name in intializer folder. that is an issue

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a create method defined in your Payments controller or in the Payments model?  At a high level, it would look approximately like,

```
def create
    @payment = Payment.new(params[:payment])
    if @payment.save
      redirect_to payments_url, notice: "Payment was successfully created."
    else
      render :new
  end
end
```

It might be useful if you supply your full Controller and or Model code as well.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I created a module name same as model name in intializer folder. that is an issue.